# Install DataStax Ops Center EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cassandra

DataStax Ops Center
EC2 multi region setup, with 2 nodes in us-east-1 and 2 in us-west-1

Ops center is installed on a separate ec2 instance, and can see the cluster, but I cannot get the agents installed. Looking at one instance, in /var/lib/opscenter-agent/conf/address.yaml, I have:

```
stomp_interface: "local ip address"
local_interface: "public ip address"
local_address: "public ip address"
use_ssl: 0
agent_rpc_interface: "local ip address"
agent_rpc_broadcast_address: "public ip address"
```

These are IP addresses, not ec2 hostnames.

On the OpsCenter server side, I have:

```
[agents]
use_ssl = false
```

Set in /etc/opscenter/opscenterd.conf.

When I start the agent, I see:

```
ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2013-10-14 20:27:49,980 failed connecting to 10.114.79.236:61620:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2013-10-14 20:27:49,981 Reconnecting in 60s.
INFO [install-location-finder] 2013-10-14 20:27:56,774 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
WARN [clojure-agent-send-off-pool-4] 2013-10-14 20:28:37,083 Tried to send message while not connected: /node-details ["public ip address",{"os-load":0.0}]
```

OpsCenter can see the details of the cluster (number of nodes, what DC they are in, etc).

In the opscenterd logs, I see:

```
Node "public ip" has an unknown topology, collecting topology info from another node now
```

Cycling through all 4 nodes.

I have ports open between the security groups of the agent and server nodes.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stomp_interface is the IP used to reach the machine running opscenterd.  In most cases, that value will be identical across all nodes.

It looks like you're setting it to an IP of the node itself, which is why you see a failure to connect on port 61620: (`ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2013-10-14 20:27:49,980 failed connecting to 10.114.79.236:61620:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`)

Comment: Thanks,for that, it foxed the StompConnection errors. However I'm still getting the:

INFO [install-location-finder] 2013-10-14 20:27:56,774 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
WARN [clojure-agent-send-off-pool-4] 2013-10-14 20:28:37,083 Tried to send message while not connected: /node-details ["public ip address",{"os-load":0.0}]

Errors. I've tried both public and private IP addresses in the address.yaml local_interface and local_address settings.

Comment: Please disregard the comment. I had a separate problem. You answer did the trick.